# WAMP server error 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp

**Disclaimer**: I know this question has been asked before by many others, but I have read quite a few of those posts and none of the solutions have worked.

I changed the *httpd.conf* file from

```
Require local
```

to

```
Allow from all
```

Keep in mind that every time it doesn't work I change the code back to normal and try a different solution.

I can access it from my own computer but when I ask my friend to try the site it give him error 403 forbidden and tells him he has no access to '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original httpd.conf has the `Require` syntax then it is Apache 2.4

The `Allow from all` is Apache 2.2 syntax. Its best NOT to mix them up within the same `httpd.conf` file

If you really want to allow any ip in the universe to use your web site and you are running Apache 2.4 then us

```
Require all granted
```

Alternativeley if you just want to be able to get to your web server from your local network something like this is safer

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Note: use of only 3 of the 4 quartiles, gives access to any ip that starts `192.168.1` i.e any ip on the local network subnet

> Documetation for Apache [mod_authx_code can be found here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html)

Comment: What if someone with an ip staring with 10 for example was attempting to access the server?

Comment: Then you could use `Require ip 10`